# How to display properties of a nested object in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using Django and Django-Rest-Framework to build an API for a battle system. In my code, I have 2 models: A parent model `Battle` and a child model `Round`. `Round` has some @property fields (`start_time, end_time, score`) which are calculated based on different values. When I access the `Round` route directly, I get the desired output:

`http://127.0.0.1:8001/battle/rounds/1/`

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "battle": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/battle/battles/1/",
    "index": 0,
    "contender_entry": null,
    "opponent_entry": null,
    "start_time": "2019-12-11T17:38:00Z",
    "end_time": "2019-12-11T17:39:40Z",
    "score": [
        0,
        0
    ]
}
```

however when I access the `Battle` route, the nested `Round`s are returned, but **only** the database fields, not the properties:

`http://127.0.0.1:8001/battle/battles/1/`

```
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/battle/battles/1/",
    "id": 1,
    "status": "live",
    "start_time": "2019-12-11T17:38:00Z",
    "round_length": "00:01:40",
    ...
    "rounds": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/battle/rounds/1/",
            "beat": null,
            "index": 0,
            "battle": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/battle/battles/1/",
            "contender_entry": null,
            "opponent_entry": null
        },
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/battle/rounds/2/",
            "beat": null,
            "index": 1,
            "battle": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/battle/battles/1/",
            "contender_entry": null,
            "opponent_entry": null
        },
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/battle/rounds/3/",
            "beat": null,
            "index": 2,
            "battle": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/battle/battles/1/",
            "contender_entry": null,
            "opponent_entry": null
        }
    ],
    "current_round": null
}
```

I want the properties to be displayed in the nested `Round` objects in `Battle`. But I couldn't get it to work.

These are my models:

```
class Round(models.Model):
    battle = models.ForeignKey(Battle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rounds")
    index = models.IntegerField()
    contender_entry = models.OneToOneField(Entry, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="round_contender",
                                           null=True)
    opponent_entry = models.OneToOneField(Entry, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="round_opponent", null=True)

    @property
    def start_time(self):
        return self.battle.start_time + (self.index * self.battle.round_length)

    @property
    def end_time(self):
        return self.start_time + self.battle.round_length

    @property
    def score(self):
        opponent_votes = self.votes.filter(favors="opponent").count()
        contender_votes = self.votes.filter(favors="contender").count()
        draw_votes = self.votes.filter(favors="draw").count()
        return (opponent_votes + draw_votes, contender_votes + draw_votes)

class Battle(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=BATTLE_STATUS_CHOICES, default="awaiting_approval")
    contender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="contender_battles")
    opponent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="opponent_battles")
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    round_length = models.DurationField(default=timedelta(days=3))
```

And the serializers:

```
class RoundSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source="pk", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Round
        fields = ["id", "battle", "index", "contender_entry", "opponent_entry", "start_time", "end_time", "score"]
        read_only_fields = ["id", "battle", "index", "start_time", "end_time", "score"]

class BattleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='pk', read_only=True)
    current_round = RoundSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Battle
        fields = ["url", "id", "status", "start_time", "round_length",
                  "opponent", "contender", "rounds", "current_round"]
        read_only_fields = ["contender", "rounds", "status"]


class BattleReadSerializer(BattleSerializer):
    contender = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    opponent = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Battle
        fields = ["url", "id", "status", "start_time", "round_length",
                  "opponent", "contender", "rounds", "current_round"]
        read_only_fields = ["contender", "rounds"]
        depth = 1
```

Note that I have 2 Battle serializers: `BattleSerializer` used on POST and PUT and users hyperlinks instead of nested fields. `BattleReadSerializer` is used for GET and nests the output. `BattleReadSerializer` is the one used in the example above.

I already tried adding the fields to the `RoundSerializer` explicitly, like so:

```
class RoundSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source="pk", read_only=True)
    start_time = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    score = serializers.ListField(read_only=True)
```

But that didn't change anything. Is there any way to get the property fields to show (other than making them db fields and re-calculating them every so often)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add **`RoundSerializer`** serializer explicitly to the **`BattleReadSerializer`** serializer as below,

```
class BattleReadSerializer(BattleSerializer):
    contender = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    opponent = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    rounds = RoundSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Battle
        fields = ["url", "id", "status", "start_time", "round_length",
                  "opponent", "contender", "rounds", "current_round"]
        read_only_fields = ["contender", "rounds"]
        depth = 1  # remove this
```